# System.IO.Compression.ZipFile issue in Acumatic 2018 R1

Tags: acumatica

Whenever I build my customization, it automatically copies System.IO.Compression.ZipFile in the bin folder. I am not able to figure out which is dependent on this file. Every build I have to delete the file to launch the site.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Add the references of your Source Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are targeting a .NET framework version that is more recent than the one the rest of the Acumatica code is compiled with. As of now you should target .NET 4.5.2 (even if the documentation mentions that a newer version is required to install Acumatica)

Comment: I'm currently targeting .NET 4.7 and none of the systems has `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` in their `Bin` folders. May be  the reason is not the target Framework?

Comment: This issue appears only compiling the custom project, not while applying  package on target system.

At present I am using .Net 4.7.1